# Cannot copy object property in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object

I have an ajax call which gathers the parent and child dependencies for some entities. Inside the success function I assign what ajax returns (data) to a global level object.

```
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajax_handler.php',
    data: {action:'get_dependencies', relation:relation, 'jobs[]':jobs, project:project},
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false, //do not change
    success: function(data)
    {
        for(var key in data)
        {
            if( data.hasOwnProperty(key) )
            {
                //Copy data object to document level existingDependency object
                existingDependency[key] = data[key];
            }
        }
    },
    error: function(xhr)
    {
        alert('error2:'+xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

I call this AJAX which is in a function twice. One for parents and one for children. I figured that this line `existingDependency[key] = data[key];` is reassigning the object thus the previous assignment is lost. In other words the existingDependency object cannot hold both ['parent'] and ['child'] properties together.

To fix this I did the below changes so that existingDependency holds both properties:

```
success: function(data)
{
    for(var key in data)
    {
        if( data[key].hasOwnProperty(relation) )
        {
            //Copy data object to document level existingDependency object
            existingDependency[key][relation] = data[key][relation];
        }
    }
}
```

But this does not work at all. existingDependency object is empty. Below alerts empty.

```
var keys = '';
for(key in existingDependency)
{
    keys += key+'\n';
}

alert(keys);
```

Any ideas why this assignment `existingDependency[key][relation] = data[key][relation]` does not work? data[key][relation] holds an array if it makes any difference.

Comment: For starters, is `if( data[key].hasOwnProperty(relation) ){` ever true? And when are you inspecting the object? Are you aware that Ajax is asynchronous (unless you disable that, which you should not, but you did). If you did not set `async:false` for the second Ajax call and inspect the object anywhere else than the success callback, then that's most likely the problem. Learn how to work with callbacks, and especially if you work with jQuery, deferred objects: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/.

Comment: alert(data[key][relation]) brings up the dependencies fine. So yes it return true. data object has the properties but for some reason it can not be assigned to existingDependency[key][relation].

Comment: I assume it is, but not at the moment when you have a look at it...

Comment: As I mentioned the ajax call is inside a function so both calls are `async:false`.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you debugged during the loop to see if it gets inside the condition?

Comment: Can you post the returned JSON in `data` ?

Comment: It shows no js error. As I stated above yes the condition is met but the assignment does not work.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: Here is the returned JSON for both ajax calls:

`{"60226140":{"child":["59562122"]}}`
 
`{"60226140":{"parent":["60226149","60226150"]}}`

Comment: @user711819 jquery clone is for DOM elements. Also I don't want to clone the data object. I want to add it to an existing object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'ajax_handler.php',
    data: {
        action:'get_dependencies', 
        relation:relation, 
        'jobs[]':jobs, 
        project:project
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false, //do not change
    success: function(data) {
        $.extend(true, existingDependency, data);//this will copy/merge "data" into "existingDependency". properties from "data" that also exist in "existingDependency" will be overwritten with those from "data".
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        alert('error2:'+xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

As for why eD[key] = data[key] works while eD[key][relation] = data[key][relation] does not its hard to say without being able to run your code and debug it. But if eD[key] did not yet exist yet then it would not be able to add "relation" to it. A possible fix for that would have been:

```
if (!eD.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    eD[key] = {};
}
eD[key][relation] = data[key][relation];
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not merge as you described. When I alert `existingDependency[key]['parent']` and `existingDependency[key]['child']` each time for children and parent it alerts children numbers OK and undefined for parents which is expected BUT next time  alert parent numbers OK but alerts undefined for children. So children are overwritten.

Comment: Checking out the extend documentation Isee that I need a deep copy for this to work. `$.extend(true, existingDependency, data)`. If you can update your answer I will accept it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Although this solved my problem I still wonder why `eD[key] = data[key]` works while `eD[key][relation] = data[key][relation]` does not.

Comment: Updated my answer with an possible explanation for that.